# Can I use a bit of code as a parameter into a C++ template? (Without adding a function call)

Tags: c++, templates, preprocessor

I have several time sensitive variations on a function, so I hoped to write a single template and just alter the few lines of code that differ. As there is speed pressure I'm trying to avoid an extra function call.

Previously with the preprocessor I would write:

```
// code.inl
void FUNC_NAME
{
    a = 1;
    BIT_OF_CODE
    b = 2;
}

// program.cpp
#define FUNC_NAME Func1
#define BIT_OF_CODE c = 3;
#include "code.inl"
#undef BIT_OF_CODE 

#define FUNC_NAME Func2
#define BIT_OF_CODE c = 999;
#include "code.inl"
```

to avoid repeating the boilerplate parts of two functions:

```
void Func1
{
    a = 1; // Common declarations and processing
    c = 3;
    b = 2; // More common processing
}
void Func2
{
    a = 1;
    c = 999; // Switched out code uses lots of variables in scope
    b = 2;
}
```

I'd consider inline functions - but ideally I'd have something like a lambda that could use all the local variables (while optimising away without needing more function calls).

Is there is some trick with the template arguments that would allow me to inject some code simply? Or maybe this is still a job for the preprocessor?

I like the template approach as if I have more variation points, the number of possible functions increases hugely and I'd like them all compiled and optimised out separately.

Comment: `if constexpr` might be handy for this, maybe with a non-type template argument?

Comment: In addition to the Macro solution, can you also show the handwritten code that you would like to avoid writing?

Comment: A lambda capturing by-reference should be inlined without a trace by any good compiler. Do you have evidence that there's still overhead to invoking a lambda? Remember that code maintainability is also important. Macros always negatively influence code maintainability.

Comment: Code maintainability and performance are both important here. inlines and lambdas do help simplify the code and I will try some performance tests with them, but to avoid other boilerplate like variable initialisation I like the template <int N> method in the answer. I'd quite like an inverted lambda - that instead of capturing variables, adds them into the scope of the function - so with one line I could create a useful working environment for my different code variations. (In this case different image sampling styles, and a large collection of 3D brush variations - too much boilerplate!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a, b, c;

template <int N>
void func(){
    a = 1;
    if(N==1){
            c = 3;
#include "code1.inl"
    }else if(N==2){
            c = 999;
#include "code2.inl"
    }
    b = 2;
}

int main(){
    printf("a=%d;b=%d;c=%d\n", a, b, c);
    func<1>();
    printf("a=%d;b=%d;c=%d\n", a, b, c);
    func<2>();
    printf("a=%d;b=%d;c=%d\n", a, b, c);
    func<3>();
    printf("a=%d;b=%d;c=%d\n", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

gives:

```
a=0;b=0;c=0
a=1;b=2;c=3
a=1;b=2;c=999
a=1;b=2;c=999
```

Check:
if you compile with gcc -O0, you can see the functions in with "nm"

```
00000000000011fb W _Z4funcILi1EEvv
0000000000001224 W _Z4funcILi2EEvv
000000000000124d W _Z4funcILi3EEvv
```

But if you compile it with -O1, you don't see them anymore, so they are optimized out.

Comment: That's a good way to handle it - means I have access to all the variables in the scope without having to pass them all back and forth to an inline function or lambda, and for simpler changes in the function I can just write the variations inside the function without needing the #include.